# Woocommerce REST API Retrieve Order By Transaction ID?

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

I got some problem with Woocommerce REST API.

My goal is simple, to check whether the order is exist or not by transaction ID. So far, parameter that works is order `status`.

this is my script:

```
$param = array('status' => 'on-hold', 'transaction_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
//OR $param = array('search' => 'XXXXXXXX');
$cek = $woocommerce->get('orders', $param);
print_r($cek);
```

but when I add more parameter like 'transaction_id', the results is weird, resulting all orders.

Comment: how you check the transaction ID ?

Comment: `$param = array('transaction_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$cek = $woocommerce->get('orders', $param);` 

not working.

also:

`$param = array('search' => 'XXXXXXXX');
$cek = $woocommerce->get('orders', $param);`

Comment: +1

Having the same problem here.
Using cURL I have tried `/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?search=transaction_id_search_keyword` as documented [here](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders) but no result.

Answer (score -1):

You can get order data using following way

```
  $order_details = $woocommerce->get('orders/1'); // 1 = Transaction id
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: transaction_id is different, your answer is for Order ID.

Comment: Yup, that's Order ID: `/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>`.
Please refer to the documentation [here](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-an-order).